# Bounding Box to list of included Tile Quadkeys

Tags: tiles

In all places where it's possible to find formulas related to Tiles & Quadkeys, it seems that the function translating bounding box (rectangular on exact Tile borders - cannot divide a Tile, however not necessary square) into contained Quadkeys is missing.

Is there a closed formula for this?